# Can't compile an example program from The C Programming Language

Tags: command-line, c

I know programming in Java, but I'm reading "The C Programming Language", second edition. It says that to compile and run a program from the command line you have to do:

```
$ cc hello.c  //assuming the name of the file is hello.c
./a.out
```

and `hello world` is printed. I tried that and worked fine.

---

Now, there is another example that prints a bunch of Celsius and Fahrenheit temperatures, so I created a file called `TemperatureConverter.c` with the given code. However, in the command line, when I ran:

```
$ cc TemperatureConverter.c
```

I got an error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
>   (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I don't know what this means. I tried double checking my syntax and it looks correct. I included the screenshot of the given code compared to the code I wrote, in case anybody notices a difference that may be causing the error:

[image: Screenshot of the given code]

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  float fahr, celcius;
  int lower, upper, step;

  lower = 0;
  upper = 300;
  step = 20;

  fahr = lower;
  while (fahr <= upper) {
    celcius = (5.0/9.0) * (fahr - 32.0);
    printf("%3.0f %6.1f\n", fahr, celcius);
    fahr = fahr + step;
  }
}
```

Comment: I just compiled your code. It works fine as is.

Comment: did you use the same commands I used to compile and run it?

Comment: Try to get the 2nd edition of that book.  The first edition was written before the first C standard was published and contains some things that don't work anymore. (The 2nd edition still has some mistakes but not so many).

Comment: I posted an answer earlier, but using `int main` does not seem to be the problem. Make sure you have typed everything correctly and if possible post your original code rather than a picture of what is in the book

Comment: `main` has *required* parameters `(int argc, char **arg)` (although they can be named anything.)  `main` is type `'int'` and therefore *must* return a value, no matter what MS let's you get away with (`return 0;` is fine). If you have a short snippet and are not going to provide the required declaration, at least make the declaration explicit (e.g. `int main (void)`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `main` does not require parameters; `int main(void)` is completely valid.  `int main()` is also completely valid, although not recommended.

Comment: Well, there seems to be two camps. The GNU coding standards camp that requires, at a minimum, both `argc` and `argv` and *requires* any code to respond to `--help` and `--version` and the "what does the compiler actually need camp?". Now I understand what `main` is from an entry point standpoint, and I don't disagree with you there, what I am talking about is coding standards, not what the compiler will accept. That I should have clarified.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Usually the focus on Stack Overflow is on, what does the standard say? what do different versions of the standard say? Then, what do different versions of different compilers actually do. The coding standards established by various groups are almost never discussed -- in general, SO avoids "opinionated" info, I think it's safe to say

Comment: The most likely answer here is that you are not actually compiling the code you think you are compiling (e.g. the file open in the editor is not saved, or is a file in another directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran your code in cygwin using the same command and it compiled/ran fine. I will say the same things others have mentioned.

1. main has the return type int.
2. it's parameters should be (void) or (int argc, **int argv). 
   You can have main() however this lets any parameters be passed into the main function.
3. Third the main function should end with return 0;
   This indicates that the program exited correctly.

In the end it should look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  float fahr, celcius;
  int lower, upper, step;

  lower = 0;
  upper = 300;
  step = 20;

  fahr = lower;
  while (fahr <= upper) {
    celcius = (5.0/9.0) * (fahr - 32.0);
    printf("%3.0f %6.1f\n", fahr, celcius);
    fahr = fahr + step;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The C standard says that `return 0;` is implied for `main` even if it does not explicitly appear.

Comment: This is only the case for c99 iirc. I did all my C compiling (including this) in c89

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely nothing syntacticly wrong with your code. Though the modifications suggested by FrozenHawk are a good idea. I noticed the linker error talks about an undefined reference to `main` in function `_start`. I've never even heard of a function `_start` as the starting point in a c file; though that could be an internal, compiler specific, thing not strictly specified in the standards.

You should be absolutely sure you're trying to compile the correct file. Use `cat` on the same argument for extra assurance. Your code compiled just fine for me, as is, and with the commands you used on Debian. It seems unlikely, but this could be an issue with gcc. On my machine, no function called `_start` appears in any files in `/usr/include/`, which implies something lower level. You might consider uninstalling and reinstalling as a last resort.